# SharePoint 2013 Server Error in '/' Application. The Web application at [Domain name] could not be found.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

We are using SharePoint server 2013 Enterprise

This is the internet facing website with the following settings
-   Anonymous access enabled
-   Integrated Windows Authentication : NTLM 
-   Authentication provider : Claim Based Authentication

When browsing the website publicly using the domain name I get the above mentioned Error, But if I login locally on the server [http://serverName/] then browse the website again using domain name the error disappears.

When browsing the website locally using the server name [http://serverName/]
I can access the website with no problems
and I am able to login into to SharePoint
When I browse a website locally on the server but using the domain name not the server name I cannot login into SharePoint it keeps displaying the authentication box as if I am entering the wrong credentials.

**Below is the full error**

Server Error in '/' Application.
The Web application at http: [public url] could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at [public url] could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
[FileNotFoundException: The Web application at [public url] could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri) +3369
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken) +569
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken) +32
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl, SPUserToken userToken) +105
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObjectFactory.get_SuperReaderSite() +441
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.AclCache.GetAclForScope(Guid scopeId, Boolean disposeOfSite) +96
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.AclCache.GetEffectivePermissions(Guid scopeId, SPWeb contextWeb) +117
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObject.GetEffectivePermissions(SPWeb contextWeb) +63
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.CombinedBasePermissions..ctor() +457
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleVisibleUtilities.get_CanShowSiteActionsMenuItems() +31
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +510
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +129
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +226
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3997
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1****

Comment: Four questions: You have the domain name public, as in `http://company.com` or just `http://serverName` registred at Godaddy or some other registrar? You have an IIS website with the same URL as your public facing website? You don't use alternate access mapping? You have made the web application available as anonymous, as well as the sitecollection, site and list/libraries?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The domain name is public and it is registered, we did not configure alternate access mapping. In IIS the site name is just SharePoint 80 and it’s different from the public domain, we have enabled anonymous access on (web application, site collection, lists and libraries)